# POSIX select Never Returns Positive

Tags: posix, unix-socket

`select` never returns when calling it with a UNIX Domain Socket server after a client connects.

My code, without error checking and safety for clarity:

Server:

```
int socketServer = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_un address;
address.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(address.sun_path, "/tmp/unixdomainsocket");
bind(socketServer, (struct sockaddr*)&address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
listen(socketServer, 5);

fd_set handleSet;
FD_ZERO(&handleSet);
FD_SET(socketServer, &handleSet);

struct timeval timeout;
timeout.tv_sec = 0;
timeout.tv_usec = 10000000;

printf("%d\n", select(1, &handleSet, NULL, NULL, &timeout));

close(socketServer);
unlink("/tmp/unixdomainsocket");
```

client:

```
echo "Hello from the borne again shell! | nc -U /tmp/unixdomainsocket
```

What can I do to fix this problem? The examples I found say this should work, but the documentation just says that is for reading. When I try using the handle set for the fourth parameter it still does not return true.

When the shell connects to the server the server and client just wait for the timeout and then quit.

Comment: May I ask you to rework this as an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?  The `-u` option to _netcat_ is for UDP on my system, not a UNIX socket (`-U`).  Your identifer `handle` appears to be undeclared.  My environment doesn't know what `null` is, either.

Comment: I made some mistakes simplifying the code as I transferred it here, my bad.

Comment: How do you know your `bind()` and `listen()` calls succeed?  If they don't, `select()` won't work either.

Comment: They do, as noted this is a simple example without error checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here: `select(1,`. The `nfds` value should be: "the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1" (so sayeth the socket(2) manpage on my system).

I'm betting that your `socketServer` fd is 3. You should be using `socketServer + 1` instead of `1`.